# How to add theme to an activity other then default

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

I have a default theme which i defined in AndroidManifest.xml under application tag. For all the activity I want the same theme but one of the activity i want different theme.

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppStyle">

<activity android:name="ActivityA"></activity>

<activity android:name="ActivityB"></activity>

<activity android:name="ActivityC"></activity>

<activity android:name="ActivityD"></activity>
```

ActivityD I want theme other than default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just override the theme:

```
<activity android:name="ActivityD" android:theme="@style/some_other_style"></activity>
```

Now ActivityD will use an other style than the one declared in the application tag.

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppStyle">

<activity android:name="ActivityA"></activity>

<activity android:name="ActivityB"></activity>

<activity android:name="ActivityC"></activity>

<activity android:name="ActivityD" android:theme="@style/some_other_style"></activity>
```